# How to compare two lists of pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
a = [pd.DataFrame([1,2,3])]
b = [pd.DataFrame([])]
```

How can I check where a==b so that it returns False?

I have tried a==b but it returns `ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled (both index and columns) DataFrame objects`.

Comment: all(x.equals(y) for x, y in zip(a, b))

Answer (score 1):

Can use

```
all(x.equals(y) for x, y in zip(a, b))
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are trying to compare dataframes with different indexes or column names.
If you want to compare their values you can use:

```
import numpy as np
are_values_equal = np.array_equal(df1.values, df2.values)
print(are_values_equal)
```

Also, you can try to compare the specific columns like this:

```
are_columns_equal = df1['A'].equals(df2['A'])
print(are_columns_equal)
```

Check this two methods in docs:

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.equals.html
https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array_equal.html